# How to add an image tag to radio button in django form

Tags: django, forms, image, radio-button

Below is what I have written so far and it doesn't do what I want to achieve. I have finished writing the font-end coding of my website and I am trying to use Django for my back-end which I don't know much of.

**Models.py**

```
class Asset(models.Model):
ASSET_TYPE = (('Motor Vehicle','Motor Vehicle'))
asset = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=ASSET_TYPE,null=TRUE)
```

**forms.py**

```
asset = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ASSET_TYPE, initial=0, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'form-check-inline', 'id':'asset'}))
```

**HTML template**

```
 <div class="container asset">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
               <div class="item">
                   {{ form.asset.0 }}
               <label for="asset_0"><img src="{% static 'Asset/Motor Vehicle.png' %}" alt=""><strong>Motor Vehicle</strong></label>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

With the code above, I get this outcome which is not what I want.
[Current Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWkTB.png)

I want an image to be included within the label tag like in this photo:
[Wanted outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya9Sq.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does your browser actually find that image, or do you get an 404 error?

Comment: It find the image. Please click the 'current outcome' link above. I have updated the image of what I see on the page. It basically create two lable tags.

Comment: You seem to have 2 asset types but they are the same.

Comment: Hey Marco, there are more choice options under the ASSET_TYPE category but I only typed in one of the choices for the simplicity of the question. First is the value and the second is the label. Thanks.

Comment: Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect .It has an example of how to loop over every radio tag and render it manually.

Comment: I checked the document multiple times but, unfortunately, i wasn't still able to work out the solution.